# Apache 2.4 - how to set PATH environment variable on Windows

Tags: windows, apache, mod-wsgi

How can I change PATH environment variable for Apache 2.4 process on Windows ?
I want to be able to load mod_wsgi with custom Python distribution bundled with application installer. Right now it only loads if Python was installed separately and python dll is already in Windows/system32 folder.

**I don't want to modify system PATH variable.**

According to this documentation:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv
- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43906

SetEnv should be allowed to set PATH in Apache 2.4 but it does not seem to work for me. Windows event viewer shows "Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: The specified module could not be found". It only works if python27.dll is already present in Windows/system32.

Comment: The ``SetEnv`` directive is for setting process environment variables for CGI scripts. In mod_wsgi that directive will result in per request variables being set in the WSGI ``environ`` dictionary passed to the WSGI application with each request. Doesn't do anything to process environment variables for WSGI applications under mod_wsgi.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Well that's bad news as I really don't want to modify global PATH variable on clients' machines. Do you know of any method of settings this value only for Apache process at startup or maybe a way of settings it only for 1 Windows service ?

Comment: Try and use the ``LoadFile`` directive of Apache to force load the ``python27.dll`` by full path into Apache when it starts. You probably still need to use ``WSGIPythonHome`` to try and tell mod_wsgi where you Python installation is. Not sure how well that directive works on Windows.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Wow this has actually worked. You can change your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Python DLL is not in the PATH and can't be added there, you can add to the Apache configuration file:

```
LoadFile C:/Python27/libs/python27.lib
```

This must be before the `LoadModule` line for the `wsgi_module`.

You may also need to set:

```
WSGIPythonHome C:/Python27
```

where the argument is the value of `sys.prefix` for the Python installation.

The later is needed if Python when being initialised from within mod_wsgi can't find where the Python installation was.

Comment: I can confirm this works on Apache 2.2 and completely ignores any other python27.dll that resides in Windows/system32 folder and would be loaded normally.
Also "LoadFile" should get path to dll file not lib.

Comment: @grahamdumpleton I am executing python script in php, but cannot run script properly if there is ```import pandas, numpy, ...``` other than ```import sys```, should I add something similar in httpd.conf? Thank you!